# Angular Protactor e2e tests CI for Azure Devops

Tags: angular, protractor, azure-pipelines, angular-e2e

After I finished my e2e tests and test them if they work. I wanted to change the Azure Devops CI to run the e2e tests. So I added these settings to the YAML file:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete JUnit files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: /junit
    Contents: 'TESTS*.xml'

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script:
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install node_modules'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Build Angular'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: run build

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Test Angular'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: run test -- --watch=false --code-coverage

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Test e2e Angular'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: run e2e

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage Angular results'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: 'coverage/front-end/cobertura-coverage.xml'
    reportDirectory: coverage/front-end
    failIfCoverageEmpty: true

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Angular test results'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/junit
    testRunTitle: Angular
    testResultsFormat: JUnit
    testResultsFiles: "**/TESTS*.xml"
```

When running this build I get the next error in:

```
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! front-end@0.0.0 e2e: `ng e2e --configuration=mock`
> front-end@0.0.0 e2e /home/vsts/work/1/s
npm ERR! Exit status 1
> ng e2e --configuration=mock
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the front-end@0.0.0 e2e script.
[09:41:05] I/file_manager - creating folder /home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[09:41:05] I/config_source - curl -o/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/

[09:41:06] I/downloader - curl -o/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_78.0.3904.70.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/chromedriver_linux64.zip
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[09:41:06] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_78.0.3904.70.zip
npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2019-11-06T09_41_31_069Z-debug.log
[09:41:06] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_78.0.3904.70
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from /
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 161 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 264 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 565 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.57 MB [initial] [rendered]
Da- Hash: ef1865e27a0ba930b45d - Time: 18647ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Compiled successfully.
[09:41:27] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:41:27] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[09:41:30] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78
  (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1059-azure x86_64)
[09:41:30] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78
  (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1059-azure x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[09:41:30] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
Found npm debug log, make sure the path matches with the one in npm's output: /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2019-11-06T09_41_31_069Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.17.0/x64/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.17.0/x64/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'e2e' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.0
3 info using node@v10.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pree2e', 'e2e', 'poste2e' ]
5 info lifecycle front-end@0.0.0~pree2e: front-end@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle front-end@0.0.0~e2e: front-end@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle front-end@0.0.0~e2e: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle front-end@0.0.0~e2e: PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.17.0/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/.bin:/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.17.0/x64/bin:/usr/share/rust/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle front-end@0.0.0~e2e: CWD: /home/vsts/work/1/s
10 silly lifecycle front-end@0.0.0~e2e: Args: [ '-c', 'ng e2e --configuration=mock' ]
11 silly lifecycle front-end@0.0.0~e2e: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle front-end@0.0.0~e2e: Failed to exec e2e script
13 verbose stack Error: front-end@0.0.0 e2e: `ng e2e --configuration=mock`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.17.0/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.17.0/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid front-end@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/vsts/work/1/s
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-1059-azure
17 verbose argv "/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.17.0/x64/bin/node" "/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.17.0/x64/bin/npm" "run" "e2e"
18 verbose node v10.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error front-end@0.0.0 e2e: `ng e2e --configuration=mock`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the front-end@0.0.0 e2e script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It indicates that it only supports ChromeDriver 78 but in the logs above it, it says that it installed the ChromeDriver 78. Maybe that there is another instance of ChromeDriver but I can't locate it. I also tried running the tests locally without any Chrome installed and it worked perfectly.

The last piece of code is the protractor config file. Maybe that there is something wrong with it.

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

process.env.CHROME_BIN = process.env.CHROME_BIN || require("puppeteer").executablePath();

const testResultsPath = process.cwd() + '/junit/';

/**
 * @type { import("protractor").Config }
 */
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',

    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1280x1024"],
      binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')
    });

    const jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      consolidateAll: true,
      savePath: testResultsPath,
      filePrefix: 'TESTS-E2E'
    }));
  }
}
```

;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the Chrome installed in agent ubuntu-latest is 77.0.3865.90. Check [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md) for installed apps in ubuntu-latest. And the version of the downloaded ChromeDriver is 78.*. That's what causes the error.

You need to specifically downloaded chromedriver versioned 77.* in protractor.
I modify your yaml and protractor config file a little bit. Please check below.

1,add command `node node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=77.0.3865.40` to install chromedriver 77.0.3865.40.

```
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    node node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=77.0.3865.40
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

2, point the chromedriver to the right location.

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1280x1024"]
      //binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN
    }
  },
  chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_77.0.3865.40',
  directConnect: true,
```

Another way to fix this is to add another -script task to `run ng e2e` command instead of using npm task to `run e2e`. This way is simpler. You only need remove `npm run e2e task`, and add script task to run below command. You donot need to modify protractor config file.

```
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- script: |
    node node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=77.0.3865.40
    ng e2e --webdriverUpdate=false
  displayName: 'Test e2e Angular '
```

In above yaml, the second script downloaded the version 77.* chromedriver, and `ng e2e` run with webdriverUpdate set to false, so the chromedriver will not get updated.

Hope you find above helpful.

Comment: Yes this was indeed the problem. Chrome version 77 was installed on the ubuntu machine.