# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline - Protractor UI tests suite

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am being tasked to work on Azure DevOps implementation of an existing legacy application. Application has a QA team which uses 500+ automated test cases. This test cases have been developed using Protractor.
All test cases are developed using JavaScript.

With Existing setup, below are the steps taken:
a. release pipeline deploys an ASP.NET application to Azure app services
b. QA person manually logs on to the VM and initiates the protractor tests.

Can we use any tasks from Azure devOps pipeline to test the same deployed application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use any tasks from Azure devOps pipeline to test the same deployed application?

To run the test with Protractor, you can use the Command Line task with node tool to run the test.

If you want to use the [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#microsoft-hosted-agents) to run the test, you need to install the appropriate version of the node tool and protractor package before running the test.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 10.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 10.x

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    workingDir: EndToEndTests/EndToEndTests
    verbose: false

- script: 'node $(build.sourcesdirectory)/EndToEndTests/EndToEndTests/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=xxxx.x.x.x'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- script: |
   
   npm run e2e  #Run the same script as you are on the VM
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

For more detaield info, you could refer to [this blog](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/protractor-end-to-end-tests-configure-on-ci-cd-tfs-vsts-azure-devops-publish-html-results-9143846f579f) or [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727583/angular-protactor-e2e-tests-ci-for-azure-devops) .

On the other hand, if your test cases requires more additional configuration, you can also install a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) on the VM.

In this case, the QA person don't need to log on the VM. They could directly run the Pipeline tasks on the self-hosted agent(create on the VM). This is equivalent to testing on the VM.

Comment: Hi @kevin, I have similar situation, I have a separate CI/CD for angular Project and a separate pipeline for Protractor Test. Instead of manually running the Protractor pipeline after successful deployment is there a way to automatically trigger the protractor pipeline once the deployment of the code is successful?